Why is there a relationship between thickness of an acoustic panel and the sound frequencies it absorbs?
When it comes to acoustic panels (usually in context of sound-proofing a room), I here it often than you're gonna need very think panels to absorb low frequencies. I don't understand why the thickness of the panel has anything to do with the frequencies it absorbs.
Surely, the thicker your panel is (assuming its has porous so air can get through), the more energy it'll be able to extract from incoming air and will provide more dampening. However I don't understand how the frequency of incoming sound has anything to do with it. In fact, since low frequencies have lower energy (as energy to proportional to frequency), you should need thinner panels to absorb them.

But lower frequencies have larger wavelengths (and vice-versa).

There are two things going on here.
There are the resonant modes of the absorber, and there is the ability of the material to absorb energy.
Just like a string of a certain tension, linear mass density and length will vibrate (resonate) if something nearby (coupled to it) resonates at the right frequency or an integer multiple of the right frequency (harmonics). The string's natural frequency is dictated by these parameters, by the relation known as Marsenne's law:
$$f_n = \frac{n}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$
The head of a drum is a 2D version of this equation, where L turns into an area A= BxH = $\pi r^2$ (or whatever the surface is). Skipping to a 3D box (as in the room you are in, the sound panel you want to make, a guitar cabinet, kick drum, etc), needs to be dealt with the same way:
$$f_{lmn} = \frac{v}{2} \sqrt{(\frac{l}{L_x})^2 +(\frac{m}{L_y})^2+ (\frac{n}{L_z})^2}$$
Where the letters l,m, and n take the place of the simple 1D harmonic numbers of the string (you can now imagine that the resonant waves of the 3D box can be in many directions and have a much richer audio spectrum than the simple string). I encourage you to plug in the dimensions of the room you are in into this equation and then start plugging in different harmonic combinations for l, m, and n. If your acoustic panel is deeper, it will naturally absorb lower frequencies, and if the room you are in is bigger, it will naturally resonate at lower frequencies.
The next thing is that there is a sort of made-up unit called a Sabin. This is sort of like how much sound is absorbed per amount of a certain material it encounters. So tile reflects most of the energy, and you get long decay reverbs. A room made of pillows absorbs more, and if you snap your fingers, it seems instant and muffled. A deeper acoustic panel will have more insulation per volume (or whatever material you choose), so the room it sits in will be a larger % of high Sabin material, and thus those longer wavelengths will get to experience more of it. Remember that these wavelengths experience less as they oscillate slowly. If the acoustic wave's wavelength is 1m, and it encounters a 1cm thickness of absorbing material, the amount of the wave in the absorber at any moment is only 1%. You can't expect much attenuation.
